# How to take a set of Date objects and display the frequency based on time of day using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a set of Date objects and would like to display the frequency of dates that occur at any given time during the day.  The chart should take into account the time of day from the date objects, but not the date.

I have a JSFiddle with my current code, though it is not functioning with the current data input.

```
$(function() {

  var data = [];
  var date = new Date();
  var date2 = new Date(date.getTime());
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
  var date3 = new Date(date2.getTime());
  date3.setDate(date3.getDate() + 1);
  data.push({
    t: date,
    y: 3
  });
  data.push({
    t: date2,
    y: 5
  });
  data.push({
    t: date2,
    y: 11
  });

  var labels = ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00',
    '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '24:00'
  ];

  var options = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true
        },
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unitStepSize: 1,
          unit: "hour",
          displayFormats: {
            'minute': 'HH:mm',
            'hour': 'HH:mm',
          },
          min: '00:00',
          max: '24:00'
        },
        position: "bottom"
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(value) {
            if (Number.isInteger(value)) {
              return value;
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  };

  var graph = document.getElementById('time-of-day-chart').getContext("2d");

  var lineChart = new Chart(graph, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        data: data
      }]
    },
    options: options
  });
})();
```

```
<canvas id="time-of-day-chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

I would like to make a simple line graph showing the frequency of dates matching any given time of day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the data like this:

```
  var data = [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 11, 4, 6, 12, 33, 12, 0, 0, 40, 3, 0, 5, 11, 21, 6, 12, 10, 12 ];

  var labels = ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00',
    '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '24:00'
  ];
```

with this options work well:

```
var options = {
responsive: true,
legend: {
  display: false
},
scales: {

  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      callback: function(value) {
        if (Number.isInteger(value)) {
          return value;
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}
 };
```

[image]